# Was Captain America Comics (1941) really trying to boost the morale of American people during World War II?

Tags: marvel, comics, history-of, captain-america

I found several of these in *Captain America Comics* (1941):

[image]

Is this a normal marketing stuff, or was it for a noble purpose?

Comment: I'm fairly sure one would have to use the plural "were" with "comic**s**". Not a native speaker though, so I'll wait until someone else comes along.

Comment: My guess would be that it's partly to get people to think "Hey, Marvel are so nice, let's buy more of their comics" and partly because if there's one thing children need during times of war, it's hope.

Comment: @Gallifreyan "Captain America Comics" is the name of the series. See *Comics* is capitalized. *Comics* is part of the name.

Comment: Are you asking whether the Sentinels of Liberty actually provided a way for children to report spies (by hooking them up with the FBI or whatever), or whether the program was actually intended to keep their hopes up (vs. just taking their 10c), or what?

Comment: @MissmonicaE What I think they're asking is if the 10c was donated to a government or similar agency, or if they kept all the profits

Comment: The title and the content of the question don't seem to match.

Comment: @DCShannon The title is a subset of the body. That's all.

Comment: @MissMonicaE Whatever you can think about "noble purpose"...

Answer (score 7):

It seems most likely that Timely Comics was sincere in wanting to promote patriotism and anti-fascism among American youth.  There are several things that point this this.

There is the known attitude of the individuals involved.  [Jack Kirby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Kirby), who would have had to draw the advertisements, was a fervent anti-Nazi even before American involvement in the war, and he was always very proud—both as an American and as Jew—of his eventual military service in World War II.  Both *Captain America's* writer, [Joe Simon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Simon), and the managing editor of Timely, [Martin Goodman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Goodman_(publisher)), were also Jewish and anti-Nazi, before and during the war.

The Sentinel of Liberty memberships were also run as a very small-scale operation initially.  The envelopes sending out membership materials were initially hand addressed by the Timely staff.  The project did not seem to be envisioned as a source of significant profits.

[image: Membership envelope]

As part of the membership materials, kids who sent in a dime got a badge, which was apparently pretty nice looking.

[image: Membership ad]

> This badge is high quality metal—the same as used by firemen and officers; it is *not* a picture button novelty.

However, once the economy was set on a war footing, there were better uses for the metal involved, and Timely ended the program and instead suggested that kids put their spare change toward war bonds.

[image: End of the offer]